# Failed to load XDebug in PhpStorm while debugging

Tags: php, xdebug

I have the following configuration, but debugging does not work.

If you have an error like me or someone who has fixed this problem,

please advise

[image]

[image]

I always get an error saying that XDebug can not be loaded.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Use the Full Path for the `zend_extension` line

Comment: @RiggsFolly I tried the same way you advised me, but I also received an error message saying that the loading failed. i tride that zend_extension=C:\xampp\php\ext\php_xdebug-2.5.1-5.6-vc11-x86_64.dll

Comment: Ok, What version of PHP are you using. Is it 32bit or 64bit PHP

Comment: @RiggsFolly I used the phpInfo () function to check information about php. Is it possible to check whether a lot of information is 64bit or 32bit?

Comment: Actually that could be your problem. I dont think XAMPP has a 64bit version, so you are probably using the wrong XDEBUG as yours is currently 64bit.

Comment: Then what should I do?

Comment: Get another (proper) xdebug version that will match your PHP. You seem to be using PHP x32-bit but xdebug file is for x64-bit. get proper one from xdebug site.